# Change input field border color according to fetched value from database using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css, codeigniter

**Error**

I want to change the input field border color by getting the value from database.

**Solution Wanted**

Input field should fetch value from database table and border-color must be changed in different orange and green color

For Example:

***SQL Table***

**p_id | product_name | VAT | Discount | selling_price**

****1| **********Coke|*10%| ******15%| **500

When user will choose ***Coke*** from `autocomplete dropdown` at view then the cost field must display ***500*** automatically.

product_name = Coke

cost = 500 (must fetch automatically after the product is selected)

If the user changes the cost field by < 500 then the input field border must be orange, for > 500 it must be green.

**View**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">

        <form name="frmOne" id="newBatch" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="customerName" style="color:#3fa9f5;" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Product Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo isset($post)?$post->product_name:''; ?>" class="form-control" name="systemProduct[product_name]" id="get_names_product" placeholder="Enter Product Name">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="customerName" style="color:#3fa9f5;" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Unit</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo isset($post)?$post->unit:''; ?>" class="form-control" name="systemProduct[unit]" placeholder="Enter Total Unit ">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cost" style="color:#3fa9f5;" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Product Cost</label>

                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"
                           value="<?php echo isset($post) ? $post->cost:''; ?>" name="systemProduct[cost]"
                           id="get_prices" placeholder="Enter Total Cost">
                </div>
                <label for="cost" style="color:#3fa9f5;" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Sum</label>

                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="systemProduct[sum]" value="1">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-5">
                    <button type="submit" style="color:white; background:#3fa9f5;" class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>

        </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
          $("#get_names_product").autocomplete({
            source: "<?php echo site_url('inventory/get_product_names'); ?>" // path to the get_product_name method
          });
        });
    </script>
```

***Controller***

```
function get_product_names()
{
    $this->load->model('productModel', 'product');
    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
        $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
        $this->product->get_name_product($q);
    }
}
```

***Model***

```
function get_name_product($q)
{
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT distinct `product_name` FROM `product` where `deleteProduct` = '0' and product_name LIKE '%$q%'");
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($q->result_array() as $row) {
            $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['product_name'])); //build an array
        }
        echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You just need to check how many form elements and target them with same class so it would be easy to find length.

then check value attribute or val depend on situation whether empty or not.

```js
$('.common_class').each(function(){
              if($(this).val()===''){ //or target attrbiute whose value you would be getting
              allFilled=false;//for validation to show common message
                $(this).css();//You can place whatever css you want.
              }
           });

            if(allFilled){
              $('#submitbtn').removeAttr("disabled");//enable/disable form button...
            }
            allFilled=false;//reset variable.
```

Tip: Please check your autocomplete code as well. It should be properly written to insert values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jquery

```
$("input").change(function () {
var value = parseFloat(this.value);
// If the value is less than 500, add a red border
if (value < 500) 
{
    $(this).css("border", "5px solid red");
}

// Else if the value is greater than 500, add a green border
else if (value > 500) 
{
    $(this).css("border", "5px solid green");
}
// Else if the value is anything else, add a black border
else 
{
    $(this).css("border", "5px solid black");
}
}).trigger("change");
```